# Add a Shadow on a Pie Chart [AchartEngine]

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart, shadow

I'm working on a pie chart using the library Achartengine, and I wanted to **add shadow to the pie circle**, how could I do this ?

I would like to avoid adding and imageView for that.

Comment: `I would like to avoid adding and imageView for that.` Then I guess your last chance to do that is by using [canvas.drawCircle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29). Or modify the aChartEngine sources.

Comment: Thanks for your recommandation